# How can I use CRTP to remove virtual method in this context?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have the following program that is analogous to my codebase. A FunctionState class which performs some sort of algorithm (potentially in multiple threads), and a Function class which controls how the FunctionState classes are used, and might do some algorithm setup/teardown operations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class FunctionState;

class Function {
public:
    virtual FunctionState* NewFunctionState() = 0;

protected:
    std::vector<FunctionState*> states;
};

class FunctionState {
public:
    FunctionState(Function* func) : mFunc(func) {}

    virtual void RunState() = 0;
    void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();

private:
    Function* mFunc;
};

#define VERY_BIG_NUMBER 10

void FunctionState::ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() {
    for(int i = 0; i < VERY_BIG_NUMBER; ++i) {
        RunState();
    }
};

class PrintFunction : public Function {
    FunctionState* NewFunctionState();
};

class PrintFunctionState : public FunctionState {
public:
    PrintFunctionState(PrintFunction* func) : FunctionState(func) {}

    void RunState() override {
        std::cout << "in print function state" << '\n';
    }
};

FunctionState* PrintFunction::NewFunctionState() {
    FunctionState* state = new PrintFunctionState(this);
    states.push_back(state);
    return state;
}

class AddFunction : public Function {
    FunctionState* NewFunctionState();
};

class AddFunctionState : public FunctionState {
public:
    AddFunctionState(AddFunction* func) : FunctionState(func), x(0) {}

    void RunState() override {
        ++x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

FunctionState* AddFunction::NewFunctionState() {
    FunctionState* state = new AddFunctionState(this);
    states.push_back(state);
    return state;
}


int main() {
    Function* func = new PrintFunction();
    Function* func2 = new AddFunction();
    std::vector<Function*> vec = {func, func2};

    for(auto& func : vec) {
        func->NewFunctionState()->ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now I have profiled my code, and have seen that there is a hotspot at FunctionState::ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes(). The issue is that this function loops many times and calls RunState(), a virtual function on the FunctionState class. In there, I perform a lot of operations that will potentially flush vtable pointers out of the L1 cache, causing an L1 cache miss each iteration of the loop.

So I want to remove the need for the virtual call. I decided a good way to do this was with CRTP. The FunctionState class will take a template parameter of the type of class implementing it and call it's appropriate method, with no virtual call to RunState() required.

Now when I tried to do move it to CRTP, I ran into some issues with the Function class:

1. How can I forward declare the FunctionState class (as it is templated now)?
2. Will I need to add a template parameter to the Function class as well?

   **3. What would construction of a Function object look like if I template it? How would I remove the need for classes which use a Function object to specify a type parameter?**

Please note that this is just a trivial version of my real codebase. The real codebase is 10K+ lines of code (not unmanageable, but a full rewrite is out of the question).

Also if there is another method to remove the virtual call to RunState() that does not involve CRTP, then that would also be appreciated.

My attempt to use CRTP:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Function;

template<class T>
class FunctionState {
public:
    FunctionState(Function* func) : mFunc(func) {}

    void RunState() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->RunState();
    };

    void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();
private:
    Function* mFunc;
};

class Function {
public:
    virtual FunctionState* NewFunctionState() = 0;

protected:
    std::vector<FunctionState*> states;
};

#define VERY_BIG_NUMBER 10

template <typename T>
void FunctionState<T>::ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() {
    for(int i = 0; i < VERY_BIG_NUMBER; ++i) {
        RunState();
    }
};

class PrintFunctionState;
class PrintFunction : public Function {
    PrintFunctionState* NewFunctionState();
};

class PrintFunctionState : public FunctionState<PrintFunctionState> {
public:
    PrintFunctionState(PrintFunction* func) : FunctionState<PrintFunctionState>(func) {}

    void RunState() {
        std::cout << "in print function state" << '\n';
    }
};

PrintFunctionState* PrintFunction::NewFunctionState() {
    PrintFunctionState* state = new PrintFunctionState(this);
    states.push_back(state);
    return state;
}

class AddFunctionState;
class AddFunction : public Function {
    AddFunctionState* NewFunctionState();
};

class AddFunctionState : public FunctionState<AddFunctionState> {
public:
    AddFunctionState(AddFunction* func) : FunctionState<AddFunctionState>(func), x(0) {}

    void RunState() {
        ++x;
    }
private:
    int x;
};

AddFunctionState* AddFunction::NewFunctionState() {
    AddFunctionState* state = new AddFunctionState(this);
    states.push_back(state);
    return state;
}


int main() {
    Function* func = new PrintFunction();
    Function* func2 = new AddFunction();
    std::vector<Function*> vec = {func, func2};

    for(auto& func : vec) {
        func->NewFunctionState()->ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Now when I tried to do move it to CRTP ..."_ Can you show us your exact attempt please?

Comment: Added my attempt, it does not compile due to issues with using FunctionState without a template argument.

Comment: Well, you need a template argument, when instantiating a template class. In case of CRTP a derived class. So what?

Comment: From my understanding: my Function class is an abstract class. It uses the FunctionState class, which requires a template argument. To template the Function class would go against it's purpose, as I will need the template information of the implementing FunctionState in the Function class, and I will not be able to use it polymorphically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a mixed solution based on type-erasure and CRTP?
It follows a minimal, working example based on the snippet in the question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class PrintFunctionState;
class AddFunctionState;
class FunctionState;

class Function {
    template<typename T>
    static FunctionState * InternalNewFunctionState(Function *self, std::vector<FunctionState*> &states) {
        FunctionState* state = new T(self);
        states.push_back(state);
        return state;
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    static Function * create() {
        Function *func = new Function;
        func->internalNewFunctionState = &InternalNewFunctionState<T>;
        return func;
    }

    FunctionState* NewFunctionState() {
        return internalNewFunctionState(this, states);
    }

private:
    FunctionState * (*internalNewFunctionState)(Function *, std::vector<FunctionState*> &);
    std::vector<FunctionState*> states;
};

class FunctionState {
public:
    FunctionState() = default;
    virtual ~FunctionState() = default;
    virtual void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() = 0;
};

template<typename Derived>
class IntermediateFunctionState: public FunctionState {
public:
    IntermediateFunctionState(Function* func) : mFunc(func) {}

    void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() override {
        Derived *self = static_cast<Derived *>(this);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            self->RunState();
        }
    }

private:
    Function* mFunc;
};

class PrintFunctionState : public IntermediateFunctionState<PrintFunctionState> {
public:
    PrintFunctionState(Function* func) : IntermediateFunctionState(func) {}

    void RunState() {
        std::cout << "in print function state" << '\n';
    }
};

class AddFunctionState : public IntermediateFunctionState<AddFunctionState> {
public:
    AddFunctionState(Function* func) : IntermediateFunctionState(func), x(0) {}

    void RunState() {
        std::cout << "in add function state" << '\n';
        ++x;
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main() {
    Function* func = Function::create<PrintFunctionState>();
    Function* func2 = Function::create<AddFunctionState>();
    std::vector<Function*> vec = { func, func2 };

    for(auto& func : vec) {
        func->NewFunctionState()->ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I removed a couple of classes that were no longer required.
Hoping the code speaks for itself, let me know in the comments if I can add more details.

Answer (score 0):

`Function` has to have a non-template type as the return value of `NewFunctionState`, so you need an additional base class

```
class FunctionStateBase {
    virtual void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() = 0;
    // No void RunState()!
}

template<typename T>
class FunctionState {
    void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes();
    // Still no void RunState()!
}

class PrintFunctionState : public FunctionState<PrintFunctionState> {
    void RunState();
}

template <typename T>
void FunctionState<T>::ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes() {
    for(int i = 0; i < VERY_BIG_NUMBER; ++i) {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->RunState(); // Statically bound!
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The issue is when I use my Function, I will have to pass in the implementing FunctionState type, which will defeat the polymorphism of having the Function interface. For example, it is not longer possible to have a collection of Functions, i.e. std::vector<Function> funcs. Edited my question to include this example.

Comment: Yup, have to go the other way then

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this can be solved by using template chaining. Here's a rough example of how it works:

```
#include <iostream>

/*
    Just make print invocations a little less cluttered for our purposes here.
*/
template <typename Type>
void Show(Type value)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}

/*
    Base class for function types 
*/
template <typename Self>
class Function 
{
    public:

/*
    For the best performance possible, we'll always inline this function.
*/    
    inline void RunState()
    {
        static_cast<Self*>(this)->RunState();
    }

    void ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes(int iterations = 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i)
        {
            Show("...Loop...");    
            RunState();
        }    
    }
};

/*
    Everything here is placed in an internal namespace, as none of it will be used by the caller.
*/
namespace Internal_
{

/*
    ChainFunctionLink works like an array of functions. Each of it's members 
    is either some kind of function object or another ChainFunctionLink.
*/    
template <typename First, typename Second>
struct ChainFunctionLink : Function<ChainFunctionLink<First, Second>>
{
    ChainFunctionLink(First first, Second second)
    : first(first), second(second)
    {    }

    inline void RunState()
    {
        first.RunState();
        second.RunState();
    }

    First
        first;
    Second
        second;
};

/*
    We won't be able to explicitly specify the template parameters of ChainFunctionLink 
    later, so a generating function will be needed to deduce them for us. 
*/
template <typename First, typename Second>
ChainFunctionLink<First, Second> MakeChainFunctionLink(First first, Second second)
{
    return ChainFunctionLink<First, Second>(first, second);
}

} // namespace Internal_

/*
    ChainFunction generates ChainFunctionLink's for the caller.
*/
template <typename First, typename Second, typename ...Next>
auto ChainFunction(First first, Second second, Next ...next)
{
    return Internal_::MakeChainFunctionLink(first, ChainFunction(second, next...));
}

/*
    The last link in the chain.
*/
template <typename Last>
Last ChainFunction(Last last)
{
    return last;
}

// Example usage:

class PrintFunction : public Function<PrintFunction>
{
    public:

    inline void RunState()
    {
        Show("PrintFunction::RunState()");
    }    
};

class AddFunction : public Function<AddFunction>
{
    public:

    inline void RunState()
    {
        Show("AddFunction::RunState()");
    }        
};

int main() 
{
    auto 
        chain = ChainFunction(AddFunction(), AddFunction(), AddFunction(), PrintFunction());
    chain.ExecuteFunctionLotsAndLotsOfTimes(4);      
}
```

Granted, it might not be practical to have, say, thousands and thousands of function objects chained together in this fashion, but it does allow you to inline (and decouple) just about everything.

**EDIT**

There is one additional caveat to that particular kind of implementation: The chained functions are stored ***by value***. If you want to avoid that, just redefine `ChainFunctionLink`'s members `first` and `second` as references. Won't allow you to pass temporaries as parameters to `ChainFunction` though, of course...